# Writing generic takeWhile with an offset in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, stream, scala-collections, lazy-sequences

I have a use case for `takeWhile`, but where I want to keep a fixed number of items after predicate is true. I'm also trying to write it to be as generic as possible for the type of collection. So something like:

```
def takeWhileWithOffset[A, Iter[_] <: Iterable[A]](iter: Iter[A], p: A => Boolean, offset: Int)
```

I chose `Iterable` as the bound, because want it to work with `Stream`. But I'm having a tough time figuring out how to make this work. If I were using a strict collection, I could use `dropRight` if offset isn't positive. But `Iterable` doesn't have `dropRight`.

The positive case is trickier. I could use `sliding` to effectively grab future items and then use `init` and `lastOption` after the `takeWhile` terminates. But `Iterable` doesn't have `init` and `lastOption`.

So what's tricky is that I want my method to be lazy, yet take advantage of the fact that iterated items can be treated as a strict collection -- but *only if* the `takeWhile` terminates. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`span` and `take`:

```
scala> val it = (1 to 100).iterator
it: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator                              

scala> val (a, b) = it.span(_ < 10)
a: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
b: Iterator[Int] = unknown-if-empty iterator

scala> val res = a ++ b.take(5)
res: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res.toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
```

Comment: Now I feel dumb, haha. At the risk of feeling dumber, as a bonus, what about the negative offset?

Comment: I know what you mean. You could also fold or takeWhile with a captured counter, but span is pretty fly. Also, you have to test for laziness if that matters. That is, this is fully lazy and you don't have to worry.